# Google Script: Inserting text in a certain position

Tags: google-apps-script

This is the code I have:

```
doc.getBody().editAsText().insertText(0, 'Google').setLinkUrl(0, text.length, 'www.google.com');
```

This works but inserts the text into the very top of the page. How can I set to where I am in the code?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer:

```
var link = body.appendParagraph("Google")
link.setLinkUrl("https://www.google.com");
```